# Docker with amazonlinux

Tags: php, docker, amazon-ec2, amazon-linux

Complete newbie with Docker, but the concepts are sticking.

Goal

Create a container locally that matches my prod EC2 instance. Upgrade PHP7 and test my application.

Approach

My first step was to create just a basic box amazon linux box. Mount it and run the commands from the CLI. Then I can slowly build up the commands to put in my Dockerfile.

Problem

I build the box fine run yum update -Y and see the updates. However, when I run **docker ps** the image isn't listed? So I can't mount it. My composerfile is as follows...

```
FROM amazonlinux:2017.03

RUN yum update -y
```

Why is the box not remaining in an open state?

Comment: Can you connect to instance outside of ansible? Just normal ssh? try --vvv option to see if can access it.

Answer (score 16):

I had the same goal of testing instances in development environment and initially I thought it should be as easy as `docker run amazonlinux:2 -it`. But I was so wrong and it took me almost one full day to get it to work!

Funny thing is when you google "*amazonlinux Docker*" it's often people trying to install "*Docker in amazonlinux*", but here we want to install "*amazonlinux in Docker*"!

We also want to install Docker in that amazonlinux, so basically "*Docker in amazonlinux in Docker*" which is "*Docker in Docker*" eventually! ;D*

### My findings:

- Amazonlinux in Docker (created via `FROM amazonlinux:2`) is so bare and empty that it doesn't even have basic stuffs like `sudo` or `passwd`.) New AWS EC2 instances do.
- In order to have your `serviced` properly working (to start any daemon, including Docker Daemon), you need to have `/usr/sbin/init` be there (via `yum install initscripts` and actually called.  However, the meat you want to play with need your shell to start from `/bin/bash`.
- You are running a Docker within a Docker.  That needs to be priviledged from the host in your `docker run` via `--priviledged`.
- You need to share the `/sys/fs/cgroup` from your host machine (it can be read-only) for it to be able to properly initialize docker daemon.

---

### My solution:

1) To fulfill the first two issues above, your **Dockerfile** can be:

```sh
FROM amazonlinux:2

RUN yum update -y && yum install -y initscripts;

CMD ["/usr/sbin/init"]
```

2) **Build an image** from it, e.g. `docker build . -t ax1`

3) Then, to address the latter two issues above, **run** a detached (running in background) container from it, priviledged, with a shared volume to your `/sys/fs/cgroup`. e.g.

`docker run --name ac11 -d --privileged -v /sys/fs/cgroup:/sys/fs/cgroup:ro ax1`

4) Finally you can **bash into it** using `docker exec -it ac11 bash`

5) Now, it's **very close** to a new EC2 instance. (Yet, missing `sudo`, actual `ec2-user` and other stuffs that we skipped in our Dockerfile to keep this solution simple.)

Anyway, now you can **install** `docker` as instructed by [AWS Docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECS/latest/developerguide/docker-basics.html).  That is, once you are in the container, do:

```
amazon-linux-extras install -y docker;
```

and then **restart** the docker service once:

```
service docker restart;
```

Now, `docker ps` **should be working!**

Answer (score 4):

Docker containers stops when they don't have a process to run. Add an entrypoint to your Dockerfile to keep the machine running.

You could do a `sleep infinity` or `sleep 99999` if you don't really have any process to run.

```
FROM amazonlinux:2017.03

RUN yum update -y

CMD [“sleep”, “infinity”]
```

Answer (score 2):

The docker container stops running after all the `RUN` commands are complete. You need a `CMD` or an `ENTRYPOINT` that runs and doesn't stop to keep your container alive. For a web service, this could be apache or nginx or whatever web service you are using to serve your PHP7 application.

Answer (score 0):

I found an alternative solution in the end. By launching BASH I was able to keep the container running.

docker run -it -p 8080:80 --rm nbsite bash